# Return multiple columns with a select max on only one

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

I want to write a SQL that returns multiple columns with a select max on one of them.
Let me clearify with an example.

Practically I'd like to have something like this:

```
Select max(from_date)
      ,func_status_code
      ,name
from table
where from_date <= current date
```

So what I want is to perform a select max on a column but also get the other columns for that row/those rows.

```
from_date   func_status_code   name
2012-08-21        1             A
2012-08-21        4             A
2012-08-20        5             A
2012-08-20        3             A
```

returning

```
from_date   func_status_code   name
2012-08-21        1             A
2012-08-21        4             A
```

I know I could do a subselect, something like:

```
select from_date
      ,func_status_code
      ,name
  from table
  where from_date = (Select max(from_date)
                       from table
                       where from_date <= current date
                    )
```

But I can't understand why the other method doesn't work.
Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: The subselect method you have done is the best way to return the data you have given in the question. It has to be done like this because translated into english you are asking 2 questions of the table. 1) What is the maximum date in the from_date column. 2) What are the rows where the from_date is the answer to part 1. You cannot combine this into a single question, therefore you cannot get the results in a single query (i.e without subqueries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is with window/analytic functions:

```
select func_status_code, name
from (Select func_status_code, name,
             max(from_date) over () as maxdate
      from table 
      where from_date <= current date
     ) t
where from_date = maxdate
```

Comment: +1 This works as expected, and although I haven't tested on DB2, on SQL server the execution plan and IO statistics show that the Windowed function option would perform better than the subselect.

Answer (score 0):

you lack `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT from_date, MAX(func_status_code) maxCode, name
FROM tableName
-- WHERE from_date <= getDate()     -- extra condition here
GROUP BY from_date, name
```

Comment: Surely this would return rows 2 and 3 (`2012-08-21, 4, A` and `2012-08-20, 5, A`), not 1 and 2 (`2012-08-21, 1, A` and `2012-08-21, 4, A`) as shown in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect query was correct.  You could also achieve the same result with a common table expression.

```
WITH m as
(
  Select max(from_date) mxdate
    from table
    where from_date <= current date
)
select from_date
      ,func_status_code
      ,name
  from table t, m
 where t.from_date = m.mxdate
```